# What is the underlying math in this relation?

Tags: field-theory, boolean-algebra

Suppose we have the constraint 
$$.7x_1+.4x_2+.5x_3<1,$$ $$x_1,x_2,x_3\in\{0,1\}$$

Then we can convert it to a Boolean expression with binary variables of the form $$(\neg x_{1}\wedge\neg x_{2})\vee\left(\neg x_{1}\wedge\neg x_{3}\right),$$

such that the constraint is satisfied iff the Boolean expression is true.

Could someone explain what math basis this transformation has? I find it very fascinating because we are going from real number coefficients to a logical expressions.

Thanks a lot.

PS. Related to to my previous question [Convert a Boolean expression to a linear expression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588099/convert-a-boolean-expression-to-a-linear-expression)

Comment: You should search for *1-0 linear programming* or *binary integer programming*. Unfortunately, the sources I looked at were, shall we say, a bit verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have n variables. There are only $2^n$ possible true-false combinations, so you can just list out all possible valid combinations, then take their conjunction.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate very much, but I know the method to do it. I want to know what is the mathematical basis which links the Boolean expressions to the constraint with real number coefficients.